# Push Notification on iPad worklight 5.0.6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a small application in `worklight 5.0.5` in which push notification is working fine for iPad and Android devices. But when I update `worklight` to version `5.0.6` then Push notification is working on Android but not on iPad. Devices and Users are successfully subscribe but push notification are not received. Here is an error detail on `worklight` console

```
Couldn't send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@ca452a56
```

Can somebody suggest the problem!?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting the WorklightServerHome folder (located in the Eclipse workspace).
That would be a good idea in general to do when moving from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6

Other than that, the error you specify could also hint usually about network issues.